# Convert colorbox to modal

Tags: php, ajax, colorbox, bootstrap-modal

I have a colorbox, but I wish to perform the same function in a bootstrap modal.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#pairsub").click(function (){
     $.post("pairfind.php",
          $("#form1").serialize(),
          function(data){
             $.fn.colorbox({
             html: data,
             open: true,
             iframe: false,
             width: "500",
             height: "500px",
            });
          },
         "html");
      });
  });
```

I found this example, but it doesn't seem to work.

```
$('#pairsub').on('click', function() { 
$.post('pairFind.php', {
    $('form1').serialized(),        
       function(data) {
        $('#myModal').show();
        $('#modalContent').show().html(data);
  });
});
```

The modal size and style are moved to the css page.

Answer (score 0):

Found it myself.

```
$(document).ready(function() {   
       $('#formbtn').click(function(e) {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'pairFind.php',
                type: 'POST',
                data: $('#form1').serialize(),
                async:true,
          beforeSend: function () {
             $('#spin').modal('show');
             }
          success: function(data) {
             $('#pairFr .modal-body').html(data);
             $('#pairFr').modal('show');
             $('#spin').modal('hide');
             }
        });
    });  
});
```